# Creating a matrix indexed by names of vectors

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

Basically, I have several frequency tables d1 and d2. Suppose I have:

UPDATE2: The actual structure of d1 is table. So d1 is obtained by `d1 <- table(datavector)`, similarly for d2.

```
d1
  Value     0    1    2    3    4    9                         
  Freq     25   30  100   10   10   10

d2
  Value     0    1    3    5    7   11    13
   Freq    25   30  100   10   10   10    12
```

Problem: I want to produce a matrix with rows corresponding to d1 and d2 and the columns corresponding to all the distinct "Values" seen in d1 and d2. So I want to produce a matrix with rows and columns that looks like this:

```
     [,"0"] [,"1"] [,"2"] [,"3"] [,"4"] [,"5"] [,"7"] [,"9"] [,"11"] [,"13"]
[1,]    25     30    100    10     10    0       0      10     0         0
[2,]    25     30     0     100     0    10      10     0      10        12
```

Notice that, there is no column number 6 , 8, and 10 because they do not appear in the frequency table. Eventually, I am trying to put this matrix into a function `image.plot()`.

UPDATE 1: I think I can allow column number 6,8 and 10 appear in the matrix, but eventually I will have to write a for loop to eliminate columns which consist of zeros entries only.

UPDATE 3: Please note that I am in fact working with 250 data vectors and hence 250 tables (each with different length / dimension). So, I am looking for an efficient solution

UPDATE 4: Please treat the above as an abstract of what I want to achieve. The real dataset is as follow:

```
> dput(head(get.dist(fnn[1])))
structure(c(0.999214894571557, 0.000134589502018843, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 6.72947510094213e-05, 8.97263346792284e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 6.72947510094213e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 6.72947510094213e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05
), class = "table", .Dim = 18L, .Dimnames = structure(list(d = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "8", "9", "11", "12", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "20", "22", "24", "31")), .Names = "d"))

> dput(head(get.dist(fnn[2])))
structure(c(0.71161956034096, 0.199147599820547, 0.0644010767160162, 
0.0147599820547331, 0.00327501121579183, 0.000807537012113055, 
6.72947510094213e-05, 0.000785105428443248, 0.000179452669358457, 
0.000134589502018843, 0.000112157918349035, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
6.72947510094213e-05, 0.00307312696276357, 0.00107671601615074, 
0.000336473755047106, 6.72947510094213e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05), class = "table", .Dim = 19L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    d = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "9", "10", "11", 
    "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43")), .Names = "d"))

> dput(head(get.dist(fnn[3])))
structure(c(0.747353073126963, 0.13138178555406, 0.0295423956931359, 
0.0139075818752804, 0.0119560340960072, 0.0151861821444594, 0.0243382682817407, 
0.00697622252131, 0.00255720053835801, 0.00161507402422611, 0.00293853746074473, 
0.00116644235082997, 0.004419021982952, 0.0018842530282638, 0.000628084342754598, 
0.00053835800807537, 0.000448631673396142, 0.000493494840735756, 
0.000650515926424406, 0.000403768506056528, 0.000269179004037685, 
0.000179452669358457, 0.000269179004037685, 0.000179452669358457, 
8.97263346792284e-05, 0.000246747420367878, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
4.48631673396142e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05
), class = "table", .Dim = 39L, .Dimnames = structure(list(d = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "30", "32", "33", "34", "36", "37", 
"38", "43", "54", "67")), .Names = "d"))

> dput(head(get.dist(fnn[4])))
structure(c(0.217743382682817, 0.49416778824585, 0.135150291610588, 
0.0331987438313145, 0.0243831314490803, 0.0431135038133692, 0.022790489008524, 
0.00912965455361149, 0.00614625392552714, 0.00937640197397936, 
0.00244504262000897, 0.000560789591745177, 0.000493494840735756, 
0.000448631673396142, 0.000336473755047106, 0.000112157918349035, 
0.000201884253028264, 4.48631673396142e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05), class = "table", .Dim = 23L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    d = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
    "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "23", 
    "25", "45")), .Names = "d"))
```

Comment: Please `dput` your "d1" and "d2" objects.

Comment: I made this example up. My original work is too complicated and too large to be copied here. But basically, I have many many data vectors, and for each of the data vectors, there is a table, which consists of probability mass functions.

Comment: @Chinegro, is it so hard to make up a small example that replicates what you're trying to do? If others here don't know the actual structure of your data, they are likely to give you answers that don't really help.

Comment: Ys, the structure is table

Comment: For others, a reproducible example would then be: `d1 <- structure(c(25,30,100,10,10,10), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
c("0", "1", "2", "3","4","9")), .Names = ""), class = "table"); d2 <- structure(c(25,30,100,10,10,10), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
c("0", "1", "3", "5","7","11")), .Names = ""), class = "table")`

Comment: That would fit with the description of how they were created but not with the output that was displayed.

Comment: FYI, doing `dput(head(object[1]))` is not different than `dput(object[1])`. It would have been a cleaner example if you had offered `dput(object[1:3])`  than 3 separate `dput`'s. Then I would not have needed to put it back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using dataframes, but if d1 and d2 were matrices this should still work if you removed the `unlist` calls:

```
 M <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=12 )
 colnames(M) <- as.character(0:11)
 M[1 , as.character(d1[1 , 2:7]) ] <- unlist(d1[2, 2:7 ])
 M

#      0  1   2  3  4 5 6 7 8  9 10 11
#[1,] 25 30 100 10 10 0 0 0 0 10  0  0
#[2,]  0  0   0  0  0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0

 M[2 , as.character(d2[1 , 2:7]) ] <- unlist(d2[2, 2:7 ])
 M
#-------------------
      0  1   2   3  4  5 6  7 8  9 10 11
[1,] 25 30 100  10 10  0 0  0 0 10  0  0
[2,] 25 30   0 100  0 10 0 10 0  0  0 10
```

Converting my examples to matrices (which inherit their indexing from the matrix class):

```
 d1a <-data.matrix(d1[,-1])
 rownames(d1a) <- d1[,1]
 d2a <-data.matrix(d2[,-1])
 rownames(d2a) <- d2[,1]
 M[1 , as.character(d1a[1 , ]) ] <-d1a[2,  ]
 M[2 , as.character(d2a[1 , ]) ] <-d2a[2,  ]
 M
#---------
      0  1   2   3  4  5 6  7 8  9 10 11
[1,] 25 30 100  10 10  0 0  0 0 10  0  0
[2,] 25 30   0 100  0 10 0 10 0  0  0 10
```

If as thelatemail thinks (although I do not) these are one row tables then it's even easier:

```
 M[2 , colnames(d2b) ] <-d2b
 M[2 , colnames(d1b) ] <-d1b
 M

      0  1   2   3  4  5 6  7 8  9 10 11
[1,] 25 30 100  10 10  0 0  0 0 10  0  0
[2,] 25 30   0 100  0 10 0 10 0  0  0 10
```

And *please*,  *please*,  *please*,  no for-loops to be used on these:

```
> M[ , !colSums(M==0)==2]
      0  1   2   3  4  5  7  9 11
[1,] 25 30 100  10 10  0  0 10  0
[2,] 25 30   0 100  0 10 10  0 10
```

You don't need to remove any zero columns if you don't create any:

You can probably create dist.list this way:

```
dist.list= lapply(fnn, get.dist)
# 3 element example built from your example

dist.list<-{}
dist.list[[1]] <-
structure(c(0.999214894571557, 0.000134589502018843, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 6.72947510094213e-05, 8.97263346792284e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 6.72947510094213e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 6.72947510094213e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05
), class = "table", .Dim = 18L, .Dimnames = structure(list(d = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "8", "9", "11", "12", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "20", "22", "24", "31")), .Names = "d"))

 dist.list[[2]] <-
structure(c(0.71161956034096, 0.199147599820547, 0.0644010767160162, 
0.0147599820547331, 0.00327501121579183, 0.000807537012113055, 
6.72947510094213e-05, 0.000785105428443248, 0.000179452669358457, 
0.000134589502018843, 0.000112157918349035, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
6.72947510094213e-05, 0.00307312696276357, 0.00107671601615074, 
0.000336473755047106, 6.72947510094213e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05), class = "table", .Dim = 19L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    d = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "9", "10", "11", 
    "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43")), .Names = "d"))

 dist.list[[3]] <-
structure(c(0.747353073126963, 0.13138178555406, 0.0295423956931359, 
0.0139075818752804, 0.0119560340960072, 0.0151861821444594, 0.0243382682817407, 
0.00697622252131, 0.00255720053835801, 0.00161507402422611, 0.00293853746074473, 
0.00116644235082997, 0.004419021982952, 0.0018842530282638, 0.000628084342754598, 
0.00053835800807537, 0.000448631673396142, 0.000493494840735756, 
0.000650515926424406, 0.000403768506056528, 0.000269179004037685, 
0.000179452669358457, 0.000269179004037685, 0.000179452669358457, 
8.97263346792284e-05, 0.000246747420367878, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
4.48631673396142e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 4.48631673396142e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05, 2.24315836698071e-05
), class = "table", .Dim = 39L, .Dimnames = structure(list(d = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "30", "32", "33", "34", "36", "37", 
"38", "43", "54", "67")), .Names = "d"))

all.names <- lapply(dist.list, names)
uniq.names <- unique(unlist(all.names))
M <- matrix(0, nrow=length(dist.list), ncol=length(uniq.names) )
colnames(M) <- uniq.names
for (i in seq_along(dist.list) ) {
          M[i, all.names[[i]] ] <- dist.list[[i]] }
M
```

First 20 columns

```
             0            1            2            3            4
[1,] 0.9992149 0.0001345895 4.486317e-05 2.243158e-05 6.729475e-05
[2,] 0.7116196 0.1991475998 6.440108e-02 1.475998e-02 3.275011e-03
[3,] 0.7473531 0.1313817856 2.954240e-02 1.390758e-02 1.195603e-02
                5            8            9           11           12
[1,] 8.972633e-05 2.243158e-05 4.486317e-05 4.486317e-05 2.243158e-05
[2,] 8.075370e-04 0.000000e+00 7.851054e-04 1.345895e-04 0.000000e+00
[3,] 1.518618e-02 2.557201e-03 1.615074e-03 1.166442e-03 4.419022e-03
               15           16           17           18           20
[1,] 2.243158e-05 6.729475e-05 2.243158e-05 2.243158e-05 4.486317e-05
[2,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
[3,] 5.383580e-04 4.486317e-04 4.934948e-04 6.505159e-04 2.691790e-04
# remainder excluded
```

Comment: `d1` and `d2` are from `table(x)` apparently.

Comment: Yeah. I tested the obvious modifications and will post:

Comment: Your method doesnt solve my problem. Because, I am in fact working with 250 data vectors, each of their size may differ from the other. Hence, you cant pre-specify the number of columns for the matrix.

Comment: You've been asked multiple times to post example data. If we had something we could rely upon being sufficiently similar to what you have there would be a firmer basis for offering programmatic solutions. For instance I wondered if the number of columns should just be  `length(unique(c(colnames(d1), colnames(d2) )) )`.

Comment: As I said, I have 250 data vectors, each has variable length, and the minimum length is 300. This is why I would rather not post them here. Because if I do, it would be hard for everybody to go through the whole data vector to check if his code produces the correct answer.

Comment: What would be so difficult with posting three  or four of then with `dput( head(vec))`?

Comment: Ok. I just learned the function dput and head. I am editing my question again

Comment: Please have a look at the question again. I have updated it with some real data. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, How come I got the following method using your method when I input : "all.names <- lapply(dist.list, colnames)" 

Error in dn[[2L]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Sorry, should have been `all.names <- lapply(dist.list, names)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `Reduce` that seems to work given the provided data:

```
# make a list including your 3 dput parts
keylist <- list(d1,d2,d3)
result <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="d", all=T), keylist)
result <- transform(result,row.names=d,d=NULL)
result <- t(result)
rownames(result) <- NULL
```

It seems to work:

```
> result[,c(1:2,44:45)]
             0            1           54           67
[1,] 0.9992149 0.0001345895           NA           NA
[2,] 0.7116196 0.1991475998           NA           NA
[3,] 0.7473531 0.1313817856 2.243158e-05 2.243158e-05
```

Comment: Hi, I got an error when running your code: 
Error in t(transform(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "Var1", all = T),  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: Can some explain to me what does "by = "Var1"  "  mean ??

Comment: @Chinegro - try `as.data.frame(d1)` - "Var1" is just the default when the conversion to a `data.frame` occurs. Read `?merge` to see what the `by=""` is all about.

Comment: I did as.data.frame(d1) and for d2 and d3 as well. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Ok. It works well for 3 data vector. However, when I add the 4th data vector to it, i got the following error:

Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Answer (score 0):

If you turn your `d1` and `d2` into `data.table`s, you can easily merge them by a common key:

```
library(data.table)

> d1 <- data.table(value = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9), freq = c(25, 30, 100, 10, 10, 10))
> d2 <- data.table(value = c(0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 11), freq = c(25, 30, 100, 10, 10, 10))
> setkey(d1, value)
> setkey(d2, value)
> merge(d1, d2, all = TRUE)
   value freq.x freq.y
1:     0     25     25
2:     1     30     30
3:     2    100     NA
4:     3     10    100
5:     4     10     NA
6:     5     NA     10
7:     7     NA     10
8:     9     10     NA
9:    11     NA     10
```

You can then convert the resulting `data.table` to a matrix, replace `NA`s with `0`s, etc.

Comment: Why bother with `data.table` at all? Tabulated data is unlikely to be large in size - `merge(as.data.frame(d1),as.data.frame(d2),by="Var1",all=TRUE)` will do it, though this doesn't expand nicely to combining >2 tables.

Comment: I have 250 tables. So how can I do it with a merge function ? Can you explain what does by = "Var1" mean please ?